# Create filename on FTP same as local name

Tags: c#, ftp, filenames

i have this code, where i generate xml file from sql database:

```
    int counter;
    int counter2;
private void GenerovaniVse()
{
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=****");
  string strSQL = "select w.KOD_....";                
  SqlDataAdapter dt = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, con);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet("ITEMS");
  dt.Fill(ds, "ITEM");
  FileStream strFileName = File.Create(@"C:\\Users\\L\\Desktop\\" + (counter++) + ".xml");
  XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
  settings.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;

  using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(strFileName, settings))
    {
      ds.WriteXml(xmlWriter);
      xmlWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

And This code from upload this file to ftp:

```
private void Upload()
 {
   FileInfo f = new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\L\\Desktop\\" + (counter2) + ".xml");
   long original_vel = f.Length; 
   FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(*****);
   request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
   request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
   request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("***", "***");

   StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(??????);
   byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
   sourceStream.Close();
   request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
   long ftp_vel = request.ContentLength; //velikost souboru na ftp      
   Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
   requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
   requestStream.Close();
   FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                counter2++;
                response.Close();                         
}
```

Problem was in: strmfile.Close();
But now when i copy the xml to ftp, the file on ftp has smaller then original xml...and on original xml i have Unicode and in ftp file doesnt have any code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to  close the `strFileName` after you are done writing to it in the `GenerovaniVse` function.

Comment: Yes, right! :) But now when i copy the xml to ftp, the file on ftp has smaller then original xml...and on original xml i have Unicode and in ftp file doesnt have any code...:/

Comment: My guess is that the file is being sent as Text rather than Binary, try forcing it by setting the `UseBinary` property - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.usebinary.aspx